# How to overwrite previous byte in file?

Tags: java, kotlin, io, randomaccessfile

I have `RandomAccessFile` with next structure:

```
1 X event_1﻿
2 M event_2﻿
3 M event_3﻿
4 E event_4﻿
5 E event_5﻿
6 X event_6﻿
7 M event_7﻿
8 M event_8﻿
9 E event_9﻿
10 M event_10﻿
```

Reading it byte by byte:

```
val eventsSource = RandomAccessFile(path, "rw")
    val fileLength = eventsSource.length()
    eventsSource.seek(0)
    var readedBytes = 0
    while (readedBytes <= fileLength) {
        val bytes = eventsSource.read()
        readedBytes++
        // End of line
        if (bytes.toString() == "\uFEFF") {
            println()
        } else {
            val parsedByte = bytes.toChar().toString()
            print(
                parsedByte
                    .replace("ï", "")
                    .replace("»", "")
                    .replace("¿", "")
            )
        }
    }
```

What if I want to change each X to L in this file? How can I rewrite previous byte?

```
if (butes.toChar() == 'X') {
   eventsSource.write(...) // ?
}
```

Comment: It's in the class description of the Javadoc: "The file pointer can be read by the getFilePointer method and set by the seek method." https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: By the way: you can't read a full unicode character by reading a single byte from a file (and then converting it to a char). You need to know with what encoding (UTF-8?) the file was written, and read it in that encoding. Doing that with a RandomAccessFile is more complex, since characters can be encoded with 1 or more bytes. To then write the previous character, you need to remember how many bytes were used to encode the current and the previous character.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt and what do u suggest to use instead random access file?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use anything else than random access file. I did point out that the problem is more complex than you think. You could do some research on your encoding (likely UTF-8). and post a new question specifically on how to deal with variable-length encodings and random access.